# Utility of shapes.txt file in GTFS feed

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification, transit

Each GTFS feed contains a collection of files, one of which is a `shapes.txt` file. As I understand, it is a collection of points that shows the actual route plied by the transport.

What info does it provide that is not already available from the combination of the two `stops.txt` files and the `trips.txt` file? The `stop_times.txt` file shows a sequence of stops for each trip, and more information about that trip can be found from the `trips.txt` file using the trip id. What additional information does the `shapes.txt` file provide?

Comment: You've provided the Answer in your Question. The shapes.txt file provides the actual route, which is often not the trivial connection of the stops.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#shapestxt

Comment: @Vince I don't really get it, what exactly is a "route"? Isn't a sequential collection of points? Doesn't the combination of trip id and stops (with sequential numbers) provide that already for a given trip? What additional information can be gleaned from the shapes file?

Comment: Imagine a bus route that traverses a park, on a winding parkway, but there are only two stops North Park and South Park.  Using just stops, you have a straight line, through the lake at the center of the park...  Now, what additional information could the shapes file provide?

Comment: Thanks @Vince, got it. So the `shoes.txt` file will not give additional information regarding trip planning and timing, since that can be gleaned from `stops` and `trips` files, but it will give the contours of a trip so that it can displayed in a map correctly - is that right?